# Google Cloud Cloud NAT Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform

I want connect my "private" network (instances without external IP's) via terraform.

- google_compute_router_nat.advanced-nat: Error patching router us-west2/my-router1: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.nats[0].subnetworks[0].name': 'test-us-west2-private-subnet'. The URL is malformed.
  More details:
  Reason: invalid, Message: Invalid value for field 'resource.nats[0].subnetworks[0].name': 'test-us-west2-private-subnet'. The URL is malformed.
  Reason: invalid, Message: Invalid value for field 'resource.nats[0].natIps[0]': '10.0.0.0/16'. The URL is malformed.

Task: migrate classic scheme from AWS to GCP: One VPC Network, Bastion Host in Public Network, in Private network all machines without external IP's. Use NAT Gateway for Private Network.

```
resource "google_compute_router" "router" {
  name    = "my-router1"
  network = "${var.gcp_project_name}-net"
  bgp {
    asn = 64514
  }
}

resource "google_compute_router_nat" "advanced-nat" {
  name                               = "nat-1"
  router                             = "${google_compute_router.router.name}"
  region                             = "us-west2"
  nat_ip_allocate_option             = "MANUAL_ONLY"
  nat_ips                            = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "LIST_OF_SUBNETWORKS"
  subnetwork {
    name = "${var.gcp_project_name}-${var.gcp_region_name}-private-subnet"
  }
}
```

[image: some result]

Answer (score 0):

```
# VPC
resource "google_compute_network" "gcp_project_name" {
  name    = "${var.gcp_project_name}-net"
  auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}

# PRIVATE SUBNET
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "gcp_project_name_private_subnet" {
  name          = "${var.gcp_project_name}-${var.gcp_region_name}-private-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/16"
  network       = "${google_compute_network.gcp_project_name.self_link}"
  region        = "${var.gcp_region_name}"
}

# PUBLIC SUBNET
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "gcp_project_name_public_subnet" {
  name          = "${var.gcp_project_name}-${var.gcp_region_name}-public-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.8.0.0/16"
  network       = "${google_compute_network.gcp_project_name.self_link}"
  region        = "${var.gcp_region_name}"
}

resource "google_compute_router" "router" {
  name    = "${var.gcp_router_name}"
  network = "${var.gcp_project_name}-net"
  region  = "${var.gcp_region_name}"
}


resource "google_compute_router_nat" "advanced-nat" {
  name                               = "${var.gcp_nat_name}"
  router                             = "${var.gcp_router_name}"
  region                             = "${var.gcp_region_name}"
  nat_ip_allocate_option             = "AUTO_ONLY"
  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "LIST_OF_SUBNETWORKS"
  subnetwork {
    name = "${google_compute_subnetwork.gcp_project_name_private_subnet.self_link}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alexander SKyzZz. Would you please share your terraform private and public subnet's firewall and routing configurations as well. I would like to configure a network with public and private subnet and it seems that you had already completed same goal.